# Ergodicity of tent map

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The dynamical system $T:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ defined by
$$T(x) = \begin{cases}
       2x, & \text{for } 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
        2-2x, & \text{for }  \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1
        \end{cases}$$
is called the tent map. Prove that $T$ is ergodic with respect to Lebesgue measure.

**My work:**

Measure preserving map is ergodic if for every T-invariant measurable set is $m(A)=1$ or $m(A)=0$ (by definition).

Let's prove that $T$ preserves Lebesgue measure. It is enough to prove for intervals $[a,b]$ that $m(T^{-1}[a,b])=m([a,b])$ holds. Since $T^{-1}[a,b]=[\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}]\cup [\frac{2-b}{2},\frac{2-a}{2}]$, we have $m(T^{-1}[a,b])=m([\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}]\cup [\frac{2-b}{2},\frac{2-a}{2}])=m([\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}])+m([\frac{2-b}{2},\frac{2-a}{2}])=b-a=m([a,b])$. Therefore, $T$ is measure-preserving.

Now, I'm stuck and don't know how to prove that map is ergodic. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Disclaimer: This is, so far, one of my most downvoted answers on the site. Needless to say, it is perfectly correct, and it answers the question as formulated at the time. I guess one should consider such erratic downvotes as an inherent part of the math.SE experience... Happy reading!*

This is to explain how to show the result with no Fourier analysis, using only infinite sequences of heads and tails, so familiar to probabilists, and to draw a parallel with the perhaps better known doubling map.

First, the doubling map. As is well known, the unit interval $[0,1]$ is bimeasurably equivalent, up to null sets for the Lebesgue measure, to the infinite dimensional discrete cube $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ by the dyadic mapping $x\mapsto\epsilon=(\epsilon_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ defined, up to null sets for the Lebesgue measure, by 
$$
x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon_n}{2^n}.
$$ 
Then the doubling map $B:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined by $B(x)=2x\bmod{1}$, corresponds to the shift $\beta$ defined on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ by
$$
(\beta\epsilon)_n=\epsilon_{n+1}
$$
for every $n$. Thus, for every nonnegative $k$, $$
(\beta^k\epsilon)_n=\epsilon_{n+k}
$$
for every $n$, $B$ leaves invariant the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $\beta$ leaves invariant the product uniform measure on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$. Furthermore, if $x$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then $(\epsilon_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli uniform on $\{0,1\}$ hence, by Kolmogorov zero-one law, the tail sigma-algebra
$$
\bigcap_{k\geqslant0}\sigma(\beta^k)=\bigcap_{k\geqslant0}\sigma(\epsilon_n;n\geqslant k)
$$
is trivial, that is, $\beta$ is ergodic for the uniform measure on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ hence, equivalently, $B$ is ergodic for the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Now, to the tent map $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ defined by $T(x)=\min(2x,2-2x)$. This time, we encode every $x$ in $[0,1]$ by some sequence $\eta=(\eta_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ in $\{-1,1\}^\mathbb N$ (the replacement of $\{0,1\}$ by $\{-1,1\}$ being merely cosmetic) through the identity
$$
x=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_n}{2^n}.
$$
To get some familiarity with this somewhat non standard expansion, note that the intervals $(0,\frac12)$, $(\frac12,1)$, $(0,\frac14)$, $(\frac14,\frac12)$, $(\frac12,\frac34)$ and $(\frac34,1)$ correspond to $\eta_1=1$, to $\eta_1=-1$, to $\eta_1=\eta_2=1$, to $\eta_1=-\eta_2=1$, to $\eta_1=-\eta_2=-1$ and to $\eta_1=\eta_2=-1$ respectively.

A key fact is that, if $x$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then $(\eta_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is (again) i.i.d. Bernoulli uniform (but this time) on $\{-1,1\}$. Furthermore, the map $T$ corresponds to a twisted shift $\vartheta$ defined by $$(\vartheta\eta)_n=\eta_1\eta_{n+1}$$ for every $n$. The proof is direct: $x<\frac12$ corresponds to $\eta_1=1$, then $$
x=\frac14-\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\eta_n}{2^n}
$$
hence
$$
Tx=2x=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_{n+1}}{2^n}=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_1\eta_{n+1}}{2^n}
$$
Likewise, $x>\frac12$ corresponds to $\eta_1=-1$, then 
$$
x=\frac34-\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\eta_n}{2^n}
$$
hence
$$
Tx=2-2x=\frac12+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_{n+1}}{2^n}=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_1\eta_{n+1}}{2^n}
$$
Now, iterating the shift $\vartheta$ is simple, since, for every nonnegative $k$, $$(\vartheta^k\eta)_n=\eta_k\eta_{n+k}$$ for every $n$, thus, $$
\bigcap_{k\geqslant0}\sigma(\vartheta^k)\subseteq\bigcap_{k\geqslant0}\sigma(\eta_n;n\geqslant k)
$$
is trivial (and the inclusion is an identity), that is, $\vartheta$ is ergodic for the uniform measure on $\{-1,1\}^\mathbb N$ hence, equivalently, $T$ is ergodic for the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Please, can you explain me who you do for  encoding of  $x \in [0,1]$ by the sequence $\eta=(\eta_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ in $\{-1,1\}^\mathbb N$  through the identity
$x=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_n}{2^n}.$

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty standard way to prove ergodicity of certain class of maps: use the Lebesgue Density Theorem and the following bounded distortion property
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{m(T^k(E_1))}{m(T^k(E_2))}=\dfrac{m(E_1)}{m(E_2)}
\end{align*}
for every pair of measurable subsets $E_1,E_2$ of any interval $I$ where $T^k$ is a bijection. If you need further details, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: To be useful, the answer should expand on the way to apply this method to the present case.