# Point of dense orbit under the action of the tent map on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

> Consider the tent map $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$, defined by $f(x)=2x$ if $x<0.5$, or $x =0.5$ and $f(x)=2-2x$ if $x>0.5$. Describe a point in $[0,1]$ whose orbit under $f$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

This is a question which is part of a course in fractal geometry and chaotic dynamics. I realise that the functions in this equation are the inverse of the equations in an iterated function system which maps $[0,1]$ onto itself (i.e., $[0,1]$ is the attractor). However, I'm not quite sure how to find the points with periodic orbits, and I'm not sure if it is best to examine the original equation or the iterated functions system to find the points.

Comment: Adapting [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2048525/) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1887485/) yields a direct solution.

Comment: Did you actually downvote my answer on the other page?

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the idea now. No I didn't down vote your answer, I actually voted them both up but I have less than 15 reputation so it won't change the public score.

Comment: @Did, I'm actually still struggling with this. By looking at the links, I understand how to find points with periodic orbits, but I don't understand how to find a point whose orbit would go arbritrarily close to all other points in [0,1].

Comment: Consider instead the doubling map $x\mapsto2x\bmod1$ and represent every number in $[0,1]$ by the sequence $(x_n)$ of $0$s and $1$s of its dyadic expansion. Then, each dyadic number corresponds to a finite sequence $s$ followed by infinitely many $0$s, hence the dyadic sequence $(x_n)$ passes arbitrarily close to $s0^\infty$ if it contains infinitely many distinct subsequences $s0^k$. Now, to pass arbitrarily close to $s0^\infty$ for every $s$, use that there are countably many such numbers $s0^\infty$ and concatenate portions $s0^k$ for every $s$ and every $k$, into a single ...

Comment: ...  dyadic expansion $(x_n)$. Finally, if one passes arbitrarily close to every dyadic number then one passes arbitrarily close to every number hence you are done. Now adapt this argument to the tent map.